# Tkinter canvas to plot windrose

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, windrose, rose-plot

Having some trouble with plotting a Windrose within a tkinter window. I cant get the windrose to show by itself, the window shows another grid behind the plot(see picture below). Is there some way I could get this to only show the windrose without the extra grid in the background? The eventual code will update every x seconds which is the reason that the plot is animated

```
from tkinter import *
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()
style.use("ggplot")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4),dpi=100)
a = fig.add_subplot(111)

def animate(i):
    ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
    wd = np.random.random(500) * 360

    a.clear()
    rect = [0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8] 
    wa = WindroseAxes(fig, rect)
    fig.add_axes(wa)
    wa.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
    wa.set_legend()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.BOTH,
                     expand=True,anchor='s')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Windrose with two grids]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are plotting two plots on top of each other:

```
from tkinter import *
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import tkinter as tk


root = Tk()
style.use("ggplot")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4),dpi=100)
#a = fig.add_subplot(111) # this gives you the square grid in the background

def animate(i):
    ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
    wd = np.random.random(500) * 360

#    a.clear() # not needed if plot doesn't exist
    fig.clear() # we need to clear the figure you're actually plotting to
    rect = [0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8] 
    wa = WindroseAxes(fig, rect)
    fig.add_axes(wa)
    wa.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
    wa.set_legend()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.BOTH,
                     expand=True,anchor='s')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh yea silly mistake, works perfectly now. Thanks for clearing that up, I appreciate it